# How to check if there is Ninject binding exists by type?

Tags: c#, binding, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

How to check, having an instance of `IKernel`, in **Ninject**, if there is specified typed dependency is already declared?

The thing is, I need only to check it, I cannot run the activation plan and actually attempt to create that instance of an object, because doing so is unneccessary.

There is no method that could help me in `IKernel` interface.

Comment: Can you explain (perhaps show an example with code) why and when you need to check this?

Comment: @Steven I have coded a custom injection heuristic, which auto-injects every property on every object that is being created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of auto-injecting the dependencies, I realized that the object creation is not that bad since it will be consumed by a controller or a service anyway.